# How to control ticket-custom fields in trac.ini from UI

Tags: trac

There are some fields in [ticket-custom]  in 'trac.ini' file, which are select value type, that need to be updated. Is there a way we can update those fields through UI? Any way we can add those fields under 'Ticket System' in the 'Administration' tab Or any other way.

Answer (score 1):

[CustomFieldAdminPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/CustomFieldAdminPlugin) provides the feature. It will be added to Trac in Trac 1.6, see [#11469](https://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11469).